# Use PDFlib in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdflib

I installed PDFlib (followed the instructions [PDFlib in PHP How To](https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/support/PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf)) on OS X by adding `extension=php_pdflib.so` to my php.ini file and it is loaded properly. 
(If I run `phpinfo();` PDFlib is shown in the list.)

However if I try to use it with

```
$p = new PDFlib();
```

I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$p' (T_VARIABLE)`

What could cause this error?

**EDIT**

The error was simply caused by a missing semicolon...
Now I am getting a `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFlib' not found` which is kind of obvious cause I didn't register it in the controller with `use`.

I thought `new PDFlib()` is available for global use after installing?

Comment: Paste the surrounding lines. Most probably you have a syntax error in the previous line.

Comment: Provide complete/partial piece of code to investigate the issue cause

Answer (score 1):

You're missing out the concept of namespaces. In this case`PDFlib` is available on the global namespace, which is `\`. In other words, you can either import it with `use PDFlib;`,  or you can use it directly w/o importing it like this `$p = new \PDFlib();`.

Comment: Thank you that error is gone :) If I try to initialize PDFlib now with `$p = new PDFlib();
        $p->set_parameter("license", "key");` I get a server error 500 and a bunch of HTML and object code in the network review.

Comment: Found this snippet in the review `<span class="exception_title"><abbr title="PDFlibException">PDFlibException</abbr></span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="break-long-words trace-message">License not valid for this platform</p>`. Seems like the license key is not working -.- I am loosing too much hair because of that PDFlib but it seems like I rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

> now i am getting a Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFlib' not found.

I pretty much doubt you got PDFlib in your `Controllers` folder therefore it seems that your code that uses PDFlib simply lacks `use` to refer proper PDFlib's namespace (or you need to use fully qualified namespaces instead).

If PDFlib is not using namespace then from namespaced code youneed to use `\` to reach it, i.e.:

```
$x = new \PDFlib();
```